# create canvas with js and align the element

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have this code below that helps me align the image to the center on any device/screen.

Now I need help with drawing the `picture(myImage)` as canvas and not `$("body").append(img);`

How can I do this?

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var img=new Image();
            img.src="myImage.jpg"
            img.onload=function() {
            //  console.log("image is loaded, yessss!")
                function my_resize() {
                    var w=img.width;
                    var h=img.height;
                    var ww=$(window).width();
                    var wh=$(window).height();
                    var ox=(ww-w)/2;
                    var oy=(wh-h)/2;
                    console.log("data is "
                        +w+","+
                        +h+","+
                        +ww+","+
                        +wh+","+
                        +ox+","+
                        +oy+","
                    );
                    $(img).offset({left:ox,top:oy,});
                }
                $("body").append(img);
                my_resize();
                $(window).resize(function() {
                    my_resize();
                    });
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/MqkRs/4/

Comment: thanks! it's working great, one question: should I ignore the "canvas.wid" inside the js? is that a typing mistake?

Comment: Haha, definitely. I updated the jsfiddle in the post - thanks for the catch.

Comment: thank you, it’s working well on my desktop, but the reason I need this code is for mobile devices, and on the mobile devices once I change between portrait and landscape, the image is not staying in the center, maybe you got a solution for that? thank you.

Comment: @LirAn Can you please accept this answer for the question and ask a separate one for the mobile issue?